# Disabling auto code generation in Websphere

Tags: jsf-2, websphere, websphere-portal

I'm developing a portlet application on Websphere and its a real nuisance whenever I make modifications to the design (xhtml page) all the html components (plus setters and getters) are auto generated in the Java bean file.

I only need 3 or 4 variables that I directly map from the bean to the web page. All the extra generated code and imports are just inefficient. It's also a waste of time to keep going back and forth and re-erase all the auto generated code. Is there a way to disable this feature?

Comment: What IDE do you use? How you call gettters\setters auto generation? You always can generate getters\setters only for desired fields.

Comment: IBM Rational Application Developer (based on Eclipse)
Maybe if there's a way to disable it in Eclipse the setting will also be there in IBM RAD.